# Autofill to last row based on activecell

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I'm trying to automate a spreadsheet as much as possible but I'm running into issues with filling down to the last row, and I can't find a solution that works for me.

The number of rows containing data changes on a monthly basis, so I need a dynamic range rather than static.

This code works for a static range:

```
Sub InsertFormula()
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4, 'SI Report'!$A$2:$F$158, 4, 0), 0)"
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F4:F200"), Type:=xlFillValues
End Sub
```

So I've been trying to build on it to convert to a dynamic range. I've tried the below, but I get an error

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed":

```
Sub InsertFormula()
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4, 'SI Report'!$A$2:$F$158, 4, 0), 0)"
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell & LastRow), Type:=xlFillValues
End Sub
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: `Range("F4:F" & LastRow)="=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4, 'SI Report'!$A$2:$F$158, 4, 0), 0)"`

Comment: `Range(ActiveCell, Cells(LastRow,ActiveCell.Column))`

Comment: There's no need to `AutoFill`. Just write the formula to the entire range in one go.